# Mount Volume for Docker Container Inside Linux Virtual Guest

Tags: docker, volume

I would really appreciate the help since I have been struggling for days...

I am trying to build a java application using a docker image on a VirtualBox guest (CentOS 7). After doing a git checkout into a directory on the guest Virtualbox, the docker image runs with the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --volume $(pwd):/usr/build-app build-monster
```

As soon as the docker container image starts, it executes a shell script that changes directories into /usr/build-app. This is where the script fails with the following error:

```
/usr/scripts/docker_start.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /usr/build-app
```

Everything else that then references this directory also fails.

Most of the howtos I read have to do with sharing a directory from the Virtualbox Host, which I am not trying to do. When I do a docker inspect I can see the mount is there:

```
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/root/build-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/JOB1",
                "Destination": "/usr/build-app",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
```

Inside the docker image's build file I also referenced the directory:
...

```
WORKDIR /usr/build-app/
COPY docker_start.sh /usr/scripts/docker_start.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/scripts/docker_start.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/scripts/docker_start.sh"]
```

The original idea was to set this up in bamboo but after build failures, I have isolated the issue to be with docker itself by running the commands mentioned above. Please help!

Comment: Did you check your container filesystem with `ls -l` ?

Comment: Hi @Faeeria. Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I gave up on Virtualbox. The problem seems to be with creating volumes on Virtualbox. Running the same build task on a non-Virtualbox agent works no problem.

Comment: I never had any problems with that on VirtualBox, so I am sure it can be done. But glad you found another way to go :)